# Select values from SQL table - leave specific column names (name condition)

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL table like this:

```
create table [Tbl](
   [_Id] int Identity(1, 1),
   [_ProjectId] int,
   [Name] varchar(255),
   [Age] int
   ...
   Primary Key([_Id])
)
```

I need to select all values but not from the columns which names started by "_" (_Id, _ProjectId). How can I do it?

(For understanding: I have many tables like this with their specific columns. I don't know all the colum names).

Comment: `SELECT Name, Age FROM Tb1` ?

Comment: It could be unknown table. I don't know all the column names. I need "select * ..." P.

Comment: @Petr What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server.
OK, I will do it in the program code .-), not in the SQL query :). But thanks for your help. P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You list the columns you want in the column list of your query. Don't add the columns that begins with a `_`.

Update:

You can build the query dynamically in for example a stored procedure where you have table name as a parameter. Use the `sys.columns` to get the column names and exclude the columns you don't want.

```
create procedure YourProcedure
  @TableName sysname
as

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = '
select '+stuff((select ','+quotename(name)
                from sys.columns
                where object_id = object_id(@TableName) and
                      left(name, 1) <> '_'
                for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'sysname'),1,1,'')+'
from '+quotename(@TableName)

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9702/1)

Comment: I assume the OP is wanting to dynamically determine which columns have an underscore rather than specify within the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use wildcards on column names.

Either select all with

```
select * from table
```

or specify which columns you want to select witt their full name

```
select name, age from table
```

Answer (score 0):

List the `columns you want separated by commas ,` instead of `*`

```
SELECT Name, Age, Col3, Col4, ColN FROM Tb1
```